# How to filter using start_query in CloudWatch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm writing a python script to query cloudwatch:

This query works fine:

```
query = '''
    fields @timestamp, @message
'''
```

But this is not working:

```
query = '''
    fields @timestamp, @message
    | filter userIdentity.sessionContext.sessionIssuer.userName = "my-role*"
'''
```

I get no error but also no results.
This works in the CloudWatch console:

```
{$.userIdentity.sessionContext.sessionIssuer.userName = "my-role*"}
```

What am I doing wrong in Python?